# Android Project in IntellIJ - Error: Activity can't be created

Tags: android, intellij-idea, project

This is an image of the situation:

[image]

I downloaded *IntelliJ IDEA*, *JDK*, and *SDK Android* for use. But I can't create an Android project because the windows shake everytime I try to create an activity or when I click "next".

I've tried to download another *IntelliJ*, I tried create other activity (no activity too but on start it shakes, too). I've searched for the solution here and on other sites, but I did not find it.

I think I won't have this problem if I would download *Android Studio*. But I want to know what is happening.

Comment: Have you configured Android SDK in IDEA before creating the project? There is known issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-193437

Comment: I had the same problem : I added android SDK in settings then I tried to create a project with an activity.
To solve it, I restarted Intellij then it works.

Answer (score 1):

Same here. I faced this issue for the MacOS version of IntelliJ. I think I found a temporary workaround to this. After installation of IntelliJ and running it for the first time, configure JDK and Android SDK by selecting configure default project settings at the bottom right of the splash screen dialog before you attempt to create a new Android project